# blender 2.81 version add-ons missing?

Tags: add-on, versions

I am just wondering if there is any information on what will be available for later versions of blender, as 2.81 no longer has rock generator as standard which is very annoying.

Because many things are not updated for add-ons, how do I know what blender will include and not include?  In 2.81 the Eevee renderer works fine for me but not in 2.8, but 2.8 has more add-ons.

So is 2.82, 2.83, 2.84 going to become even more less useful unless I pay for everything? If even someone has the add-ons for the newer release that is?

Comment: That is precisely why I have two versions of Blender on my PC, namely 2.79b and 2.81. I just changed the folder name of 2.79b and same to another folder inside, before downloading 2.81.

Answer (score 1):

The rock generator has been merged in the "Add Mesh : Extra Objects" Add-on.

You can then go to Add > Mesh > Rock Generator.

You can find such informations by visiting https://developer.blender.org/